Struggling using JS to create a HTML element and replace it with new content (document.createElement)
I am currently working on a on a small project, if you can call it that way.
It’s pretty simple two buttons which affect a <p> element that alone works, but now I decided to use Objects and DOM to get a better understanding of it. So I added a ranking below the p which should call 1st, 2nd… and so on depending on which number you are.
HTML
<body>

  <div id="OuterShell">

    <div id="ContainsButtons">
      <button id="AddPs">Add</button>
      <button id="RemovePs">Remove</button>
    </div>
    <div id="ContainsPs">
      <p id="text" class="text">0</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="./TestJS.js"></script>
</body>

Now my problem is that it either deletes the new ranking which I currently added, deleting everything or deleting nothing at all and just add more and more paragraphs.
JS
var Text = document.getElementById("text");
var B1 = document.getElementById("AddPs");
var B2 = document.getElementById("RemovePs");
var div1 = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[2];

var counter = 0;
var x = false;

function AddOne() {
  if (counter < 10) {
    counter++
    update();
  } else {
    Text.innerText = TextStored.Limit;
  }
}

function RemoveOne() {
  if (counter > 0) {
    counter--
    update();
  } else {
    Text.innerText = TextStored.Limit;
  }
}

function update() {
  Text.innerText = counter;
  var ranking = document.createElement("p");
  var ItsText = document.createTextNode(TextStored.Text[counter]);
  ranking.appendChild(ItsText);
  div1.appendChild(ranking);

  if (x) {
    var deleted = ranking.parentNode;
    deleted.removeChild(ranking);
  }

  x = true;
  return ranking;
}

var TextStored = {
  Text: [0, "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th", "6th", "7th", "8th", "9th", "10th"],
  Limit: "You reached the limit"
};

B1.onclick = AddOne;
B2.onclick = RemoveOne;

I tried it first myself different placing of the code, use different variables even tried to solve it in a complicated way which doesn’t work either then I looked it up online at the end but I didn’t found something useful (or didn’t understand/google it right.
Nothing worked I only got a better understanding why it doesn’t work and how the PC reads the code.
##Expections
When I press one button (for example Add) it should output this
1
1st

When I press Add again it should update both numbers
2
2nd

I am not able to update the second one and don’t know what to do.

What is that you're trying to do with that x thing in if(x){ ? Do you really want to append elements like "1st, 2nd..." or you just want to update an element's textContent? If so - why don't you do that? You already have the base-code to do so. And everything will be working fine. (And as I said, remove that if statement)

Also, why would you ever want to show to the user "You reached the limit" instead of the ordinal number? If you really need to show a warning - use another element for those warnings - if really needed.

The x was meant to prevent it from deleting the first output since I can’t put the delete code over the create code

That's exactly why I removed that  unnecessary x variable from my solution.

Would looping the counter be a feasible idea? Example: https://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/a5bwyhzc/

You're complicating things a little, you already have the knowledte on hot to change text of an element, no need to create one, query it etc etc. Define it in HTML (<div id="rank">) and access it via JS.  Also use rather addEventListener instead of the overriding on* handler.
Notice the new element in HTML and the updated update() function:


var Text = document.getElementById("text");
var Rank = document.getElementById("rank");
var B1 = document.getElementById("AddPs");
var B2 = document.getElementById("RemovePs");
var ContainsPs = document.getElementById("ContainsPs");

var counter = 0;

function AddOne() {
  if (counter < 10) {
    counter++
    update();
  } else {
    Text.textContent = TextStored.Limit;
  }
}

function RemoveOne() {
  if (counter > 0) {
    counter--
    update();
  } else {
    Text.textContent = TextStored.Limit;
  }
}

function update() {
  Text.textContent = counter;
  Rank.textContent = TextStored.Text[counter];
}

var TextStored = {
  Text: [0, "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th", "6th", "7th", "8th", "9th", "10th"],
  Limit: "You reached the limit"
};

B1.addEventListener("click", AddOne);
B2.addEventListener("click", RemoveOne);
<div id="OuterShell">
  <div id="ContainsButtons">
    <button id="AddPs">Add</button>
    <button id="RemovePs">Remove</button>
  </div>
  <div id="ContainsPs">
    <p id="text" class="text">0</p>
    <p id="rank" class="text"></p>
  </div>
</div>




I know I could done it the same way but that’s not the point I created this small „project“ to practice Objects and DOM manipulation. I didn’t add an empty  element because the book from Jon Ducket told me not to do that.

The example below adds and removes the number value by one with the corresponding <button>, it's minimum value is 0 and it has no maximum. Details are commented in example.


// Define counter variable outside of function
let num = 0;
// Register an element that wraps around both <button>s to the "click" event
document.querySelector(".btnGrp").onclick = count;

function count(e) {
  // Reference elements that displays results
  const N = document.getElementById("number");
  const R = document.getElementById("rank");
  /**
   * This is a ternary, it's shorthand for: if, else if, and else.
   * e.target is the element the user clicked
   * if the element clicked has id of "add" dir = 1
   * else if the element clicked has id of "rem" dir = -1
   * else dir = 0
   */
  let dir = e.target.id === "add" ? 1 : e.target.id === "rem" ? -1 : 0;
  // Increment num
  num = num + dir;
  /**
   * if num is less than 1 num = 0 
   * The results are "0" and blank
   * The function ends now going no further.
   */
  if (num < 1) {
    num = 0;
    N.textContent = "0";
    R.textContent = "";
    return;
  }
  // Convert num from number into string
  const str = num.toString();
  /**
   * if num is 11 to 13 ord = "th"
   * else if str ends with a "1" ord = "st"
   * else if str ends with a "2" ord = "nd"
   * else if str ends with a "3" ord = "rd"
   * else ord = "th"
   */
  let ord = num > 10 && num < 14 ? "th" : str.endsWith("1") ? "st" : str.endsWith("2") ? "nd" : str.endsWith("3") ? "rd" : "th";
  // Display results
  N.textContent = num;
  R.textContent = num + ord;
}
<section class="btnGrp">
  <button id="add">ADD</button>
  <button id="rem">REMOVE</button>
</section>
<p id="number">0</p>
<p id="rank"></p>



